# How to fix my if statements for aspect ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have code that creates a rectangle based on user input for height and width. I want the width to always be 250 and the height to adjust based on the aspect ratio with a max of 250. For whatever reason, my if statements don't seem to work when the height is greater than the width. Otherwise it seems to work.

I've tried moving the if statements around in the code a bit and changing them to if else but nothing seems to make a difference.

```
private readonly double maxWidth = 250;
private readonly double maxHeight = 250;

Rectangle rect = null;


public void CreateARectangle() 
{
    if (rect == null) 
    {
        // Creates a Rectangle  
        rect = new Rectangle();

        double aspect = xcoord / ycoord;
        rect.Width = maxWidth;
        rect.Height = maxWidth / aspect;

        // Add Rectangle to the Grid.  
        can.Children.Add(rect);
    }

    if (rect.Width > maxWidth && rect.Height > maxHeight)
    {
        rect.Width = maxWidth;
        rect.Height = maxWidth * (xcoord / ycoord);
    } 
    else if (rect.Width < maxWidth && rect.Height > maxHeight) 
    {
        rect.Width = maxWidth;
        rect.Height = maxWidth * (xcoord / ycoord);
    } 
    else
    {

        double aspect = (xcoord / ycoord);
        rect.Width = maxWidth;
        rect.Height = maxWidth / aspect;
    }
}
```

It just seems like the code doesn't enter the if statements properly but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to this...thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do `xcoord` and `ycoord` represent?

Comment: sorry, those are what the user inputs for width and height

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple example that:

- Width always sets to `250`
- will adjust the height depending on the coefficient
- will display information when the height is higher than `250` or higher than the width

CODE:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    double maxWidth = 250;
    double maxHeight = 250;

    double yourWidth = 800; // INPUT
    double yourHeight = 100; // INPUT

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    SolidColorBrush colorbrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    colorbrush.Color = Colors.SteelBlue;
    rect.Fill = colorbrush;

    var ratioX = yourWidth / maxWidth;

    var newWidth = maxWidth;
    var newHeight = yourHeight / ratioX;

    if (newHeight > maxHeight) Console.WriteLine("Height is too long...");

    rect.Width = newWidth;
    rect.Height = newHeight;

    Main.Children.Add(rect);
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="Main">
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your If-Statement

```
if (rect.Width > maxWidth && rect.Height > maxHeight)
    {
        rect.Width = maxWidth;
        rect.Height = maxWidth * (xcoord / ycoord);
    }
```

can never be true, because you set your `rect.Width` equal to `maxWidth`and so both of your Conditions cant be true (Maximum the `rect.Height > maxHeight`)

And the same is with your second If-Statement:

`if(rect.Width < maxWidth)`

can never be true, because they have always the same Value.

That is why your Application is always going into the

```
else
    {
        double aspect = (xcoord / ycoord);
        rect.Width = maxWidth;
        rect.Height = maxWidth / aspect;
    }
```